# Table creation in sqlite3 isn't working

Tags: c, database, sqlite

I have a problem in the creation of a one table in sqlite3. Basically, the code (language c) that I use in the creation is the following:

```
do{
    sprintf(buffer, "CREATE TABLE new_tab AS SELECT * FROM fileslog WHERE file_owner='%s' AND  state='%s';", file_owner, state);

    rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, buffer, -1, &result, NULL);

 }while((rc == SQLITE_BUSY) || (rc == SQLITE_LOCKED));
```

My problem is that no any table is created when I execute this code. I have printed the rc variable to see the possible errors, but its value is 0 (SQLITE_OK). I don't know that it's happening neither where is the error.

Comment: "My problem is that any table is created when I execute this code." Isn't that what `CREATE TABLE` is supposed to do?

Comment: Did you forget [sqlite3_step()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only *preparing* the SQL statement for execution.

To *actually* execute it, call [sqlite3_step](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_step).

The [steps involved according to the the SQL Statement Object documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_stmt) are:

1. Create the object using [sqlite3_prepare_v2()](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_prepare) or a related function.
2. Bind values to [host parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_bind_blob) using the sqlite3_bind_*() interfaces.
3. Run the SQL by calling [sqlite3_step()](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_step) one or more times.
4. Reset the statement using [sqlite3_reset()](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_reset) then go back to step 2. Do this zero or more times.
5. Destroy the object using [sqlite3_finalize()](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_finalize).

*(above list and links lifted from the [official documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html).)*

Answer (score 1):

`sqlite_prepare_v2()` followed by `sqlite3_step()`s and `sqlite3_finalizer() as suggested by Lasse V. Karlsen is one way to run the SQL.

`sqlite3_exec()` is a simpler way for `CREATE TABLE` and other non-`SELECT` queries where you don't need to get result rows. As a side effect, you can't use variable binding (that can be useful for e.g. `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries).